# Is there any option available to fix a chrome extension always on top of another window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Currently i'm developing google chrome extension. The Problem is when i click outside the extension it goes behind another window. But the requirement is I always want to display the window  even if click outside.

I tried using the below code

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
    let url = chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html");
    chrome.windows.create({
       url,
       type: "panel",
       height: 650,
       width: 520,
       focused: true,
       left: 1000,
       top: 100
    });
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(data => {
        chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(wId => {
            if (data.id != wId)
                chrome.windows.update(data.id, {'focused': true})  
        })
    })
});
```

It creating new window but it is not fixed. I want the window to always on the top of another window (Floating)

Comment: No, there's no such option. You can add the UI into the web page as a DOM element or inside an iframe.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that

Comment: Look for examples that use `web_accessible_resources` `iframe`

Comment: In the future you can probably use the new Document Picture-in-Picture API.

Answer (score 1):

save the id of the window you opened and try this code:

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(wId => {
    if (<ext_window_id> != wId)
        chrome.windows.update(<ext_window_id>, {'focused': true})
})
```

Comment: This didn't work. Do you have any other solution for that

Comment: I test the code before posting it and it works here.
Please show your code in its entirety.

Comment: chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
    let url = chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html");
      chrome.windows.create({
        url,
        type: "panel",
        // height: 650,
        width: 520,
        focused: true,
        left: 1000,
        // top: 100,
      });
      chrome.windows.getCurrent(data=>{
        chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(wId => {
    if (data.id != wId)
        chrome.windows.update(data.id, {'focused': true})
})
 })  
});  This is my current code

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the onFocusChanged listener inside a callback function.
This way you clone the listener every time you click on the action.
Also, when the SW wakes up after it has gone into hibernation it doesn't "see" the listener.

```
var wId;
chrome.storage.session.get('wId', itm => {
    wId = itm.wId
});
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(t => {
    var url = chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html");
    chrome.windows.create({
        url,
        type: "panel",
        left:1000, top:100,
        height:650, width: 400,
        focused: true
    }, x =>
        chrome.storage.session.set({'wId': x.id}, _ => {
            wId = x.id
        })
    )
});
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(fcwId => {
    if (typeof wId === 'undefined')
        return;
    if (wId != fcwId)
        chrome.windows.update(wId, {'focused': true}, w => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                console.warn(chrome.runtime.lastError)
        })
})
```

Comment: This is fine. But i don't want to always focus on it. I need like i can work on another window even if it is there. But this get focused even i minimized the window

Comment: devil makes pots but no lids.